# Will high value of keep-alive help increase Google crawl rate

Tags: google, googlebot

I have a website with thousands of pages with most of them indexed. The pages receive frequent updates (usually monthly). Google's crawl rate is good, but not enough to capture all the changes before a month's close. My current value of keep-alive is 5. Will increasing this have an impact on the crawl rate by helping crawl speed (due to persistent connection)?